# Converting factor to numerical giving odd results

Tags: r

I have a data frame and I need to convert 2 variables from factor to numerical variables. I have a

```
        df$QTY.SHIPPED=as.numeric(df$QTY.SHIPPED)
        df$PRE.TAX.TOTAL.=as.numeric(df$PRE.TAX.TOTAL.)
```

The quantity shipped converts well. Because it is already in integer format. Howerver, the PRE.TAX.TOTAL. does not convert well.

```
    PRE.TAX.TOTAL.(Factor)  PRE.TAX.TOTAL.(Numerical)
       57.8                     3856
       210                      2159
```

Does anybody have an idea why it is converting this way?

Thank you

Comment: Try `as.numeric(as.character((df$QTY.SHIPPED))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert to character first and then to numeric. Otherwise it will just be converting to the underlying integer that encodes the factor

```
> v<-factor(c("57.8","82.9"))
> as.numeric(v)
[1] 1 2
> as.numeric(as.character(v))
[1] 57.8 82.9
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually could read the documentation. Typing `?factor` in console produces

> Warning
>
> The interpretation of a factor depends on both the codes and the
>   "levels" attribute. Be careful only to compare factors with the same
>   set of levels (in the same order). In particular, as.numeric applied
>   to a factor is meaningless, and may happen by implicit coercion. To
>   transform a factor f to approximately its original numeric values,
>   as.numeric(levels(f))[f] is recommended and slightly more efficient
>   than as.numeric(as.character(f)).

Thus, the more proper way would probably be `as.numeric(levels(f))[f]`